Mockito Test Method Transport.send inside completable future
So I'm struggling with writing a mockito test method for a method having this piece of code
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    LOGGER.info("create Transport to send mail");
                    Transport.send(message);
                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });

so Ive mocked ExecutorService and Future and tried doing this
        when(mockExecutor.submit(any(Runnable.class))).thenReturn(mockFuture);

but seeing this error
error: no suitable method found for thenReturn(Future<CAP#1>)
        when(mockExecutor.submit(any(Runnable.class))).thenReturn(mockFuture);
                                                      ^
    method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Future<CAP#2>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Future<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Future<CAP#2>)
    method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Future<CAP#2>,Future<CAP#2>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Future<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Future<CAP#2>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?


<?> means the generic type is unknown (and incompatible with any other unknown type). What do you want to test exactly? Casting to the raw type could help, as could stubbing with the doReturn form of Mockito. Do you want to invoke the runnable too? In that case, you might want to implement a dummy executor service (or wire a singlethreadexecutor)

This question is similar to: Mockito: Stubbing Methods That Return Type With Bounded Wild-Cards. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
